# Explain structure of virtual memory?

Tags: ram

In memory when a data is written after the program is compiled.. let's say data is written at address 0x******** for some int x =3; Now will this data be written in this address or it is just the address where data is starting to write on memory and continues to its subsequent memory addresses. For example when I use x command in debugger to examine memory, it gives us many addresses.Are these addresses inside this particular memory address or are they written to subsequent memory addresses.

Comment: Nothing to do with Ubuntu...http://searchstorage.techtarget.com/definition/virtual-memory